# See if a ruby string has whitespace in it

Tags: ruby, string

I want to see if a string has any white space in it.  What's the most effective way of doing this in ruby?

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If by "white space" you mean in the Regular Expression sense, which is any of space character, tab, newline, carriage return or (I think) form-feed, then any of the answers provided will work:

```
s.match(/\s/)
s.index(/\s/)
s =~ /\s/
```

or even (not previously mentioned)

```
s[/\s/]
```

If you're only interested in checking for a space character, then try your preference of

```
s.match(" ")
s.index(" ")
s =~ / /
s[" "]
```

From irb (Ruby 1.8.6):

```
s = "a b"
puts s.match(/\s/) ? "yes" : "no" #-> yes
puts s.index(/\s/) ? "yes" : "no" #-> yes
puts s =~ /\s/ ? "yes" : "no" #-> yes
puts s[/\s/] ? "yes" : "no" #-> yes

s = "abc"
puts s.match(/\s/) ? "yes" : "no" #-> no
puts s.index(/\s/) ? "yes" : "no" #-> no
puts s =~ /\s/ ? "yes" : "no" #-> no
puts s[/\s/] ? "yes" : "no" #-> no
```

Comment: Bringing this up-to-date, [String#match?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) made its debut in Ruby v2.4, so one can now also write `s.match?(/\s/)`.

Answer (score 8):

```
some_string.match(/\s/)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
"text message".include?(' ') #=> true
"text_message".include?(' ') #=> false
```

Answer (score 4):

It is usually done like this:

```
str =~ /\s/
```

You can read about regular expressions [here](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/regexp.html).

Answer (score 2):

you can use index

```
"mystring".index(/\s/)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy using count for this.

```
"hello 1".count("")   #=> 0
"hello 1".count(" ")  #=> 1
" hello 1".count(" ") #=> 2


"hello 1".count(" ") > 0 #=> true
```